# Dropwizard, JDBI, Guice, & Governator

Tags: guice, dropwizard

I've been trying to take advantage of Guice & Governator with Dropwizard & JDBI so that I can use lazy singleton's for my DBI class.  However, I've been hitting all sorts of issues.  I've followed the instructions outlined here for creating the GovernatorInjectorFactory:
https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice

However, I start hitting classpath issues between Governator and Dropwizard.  I've had to exclude the following modules in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
        <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
        <version>${com.netflix.governator.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**Note** I am using Governator version 1.3.3

But now I'm hitting issues where it's stating no base packages have been specified, which at first glance and seeing a NoSuchMethodError I'm thinking it may be yet another classpath issue:

```
WARN  [2015-04-08 07:13:04,445] 
com.netflix.governator.lifecycle.ClasspathScanner: No base packages specified - no classpath scanning will be done
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.binder.AnnotatedBindingBuilder.toProvider(Ljavax/inject/Provider;)Lcom/google/inject/binder/ScopedBindingBuilder;
    at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.InternalJerseyModule.configure(InternalJerseyModule.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.BootstrapModule.configure(BootstrapModule.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.JerseyModule.configureServlets(JerseyModule.java:15)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:217)
    at com.netflix.governator.guice.LifecycleInjector.createChildInjector(LifecycleInjector.java:327)
    at com.netflix.governator.guice.LifecycleInjector.createInjector(LifecycleInjector.java:394)
    at com.netflix.governator.guice.LifecycleInjector.createInjector(LifecycleInjector.java:348)
    at com.gordysc.GovernatorInjectorFactory.create(GovernatorInjectorFactory.java:15)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.initInjector(GuiceBundle.java:105)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.initialize(GuiceBundle.java:96)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.addBundle(Bootstrap.java:142)
    at com.gordysc.ExampleApplication.initialize(ExampleApplication.java:22)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:71)
    at com.gordysc.ExampleApplication.main(ExampleApplication.java:32)
```

However, inside my application, I'm using the same setup they show on the dropwizard-guice github page:

```
public final class ExampleApplication extends Application<ExampleConfiguration> {

    private GuiceBundle<ExampleConfiguration> bundle;

    @Override
    public void initialize( io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration> bootstrap ) {
        //@formatter:off
        bundle = GuiceBundle.<ExampleConfiguration>newBuilder()
                            .addModule( new ExampleModule() )
                            .enableAutoConfig( getClass().getPackage().getName() )
                            .setConfigClass( ExampleConfiguration.class )
                            .setInjectorFactory( new GovernatorInjectorFactory() )
                            .build();
        //@formatter:on
        bootstrap.addBundle( bundle );
    };

    @Override
    public void run( ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment ) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        new ExampleApplication().run( args );
    }
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this??? Or even better, does anyone know a working example for Governator & Dropwizard 0.8.0 I could use to compare against? I've added my ExampleModule & the GovernatorInjectorFactory below for completeness in case I'm just an idiot and did something dumb there:

```
final class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
    private DBIFactory dbiFactory() {
        return new DBIFactory();
    }

    @Inject
    @Provides
    @LazySingleton
    private DBI dbi( ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment, DBIFactory factory ) {
        return factory.build( environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

final class GovernatorInjectorFactory implements InjectorFactory {
    @Override
    public Injector create( final Stage stage, final List<Module> modules ) {
        //@formatter:off
        return LifecycleInjector.builder()
                                .inStage( stage )
                                .withModules( modules )
                                .build()
                                .createInjector();
        //@formatter:on
    }
}
```

**Note** Packages/imports have been excluded for posting, but all of these classes exist in the same package.

Comment: Looks like Governator is pulling in Guice 3 while dropwizar-guice is pulling in 4.0-beta5. Could be some conflict there...

Comment: So, I tried excluding Guice on Governator, but no dice.  I've tried excluding Guice on dropwizard-guice (which seems flat out wrong), and no luck.  I'm thinking this is just broken in dropwizard-guice....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I missed the guice-multibindings module Governator was pulling in...

You will need to exclude the following for Governator 1.3.3:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
        <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Special props to Johnathon Haber for pointing me to this fix:
https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice/issues/54